# Error while migrating database (Laravel): table already exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have installed Laravel's auth and chatter forum package. When I tried to migrate the database, I got this error:

```
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view alr eady exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `email_verified_at` timestamp null, `password` va rchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb 4_unicode_ci')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\Application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Databas e\Connection.php:664

    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll  format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make th is exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the databa se's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
    664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 T able 'users' already exists")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\Application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Databa se\Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\Application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Databa se\Connection.php:458

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

I tried to migrate with the command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Since Users already exists, find that file and comment out everything in the Up function. This will allow the migration to continue without deleting the file.

Answer (score 3):

If you check at the error trace, it says almost at the bottom:

> Base table or view already exists: 1050 T able 'users' already
>   exists")
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Databa
>   se\Connection.php:458

This means that the `users` table already exists so when you run your migrations it is trying to create a table that is already created in your database, hence the error.

So tho undo this migrations before running them again, you could do:

```php
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Check the documentations regarding [rolling back migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#rolling-back-migrations).

This will run the `down()` function of every migration file already migrated in your system before actually running the `up()` ones.

If you go to your `users` migration, you can see the `down()` function, it should look like this:

**database/migrations/XXXX_XX_XX_XXXXXX_create_users_table.php**

```php
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

Whenever you create a migration, always implement the `down()` method, to make use of the rolling back options.

Comment: Migrate:refresh shows same error. When I try to roll back migration shows "Nothing to roll back". Down function is looking like that.

Comment: If you go to your `migrations` table (the one that logs the migrations already run) it lists the migration of the users table? If not, you'll need to drop the `users` table manually (directly in your database)

Comment: Migrations table is empty. Tried to drop users table, but nothing!

Comment: If you already dropped the `users` table there shouldn't be any error (because there shouldn't be any conflict). Are you sure you are using the same dabatase connection that you are configuring?

Answer (score 0):

Well, always that I install laravel i get the same error. Try changing code in your migration files like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email',64{ADD THIS PARAMETER})->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

You have to add a second parameter to strings (max length) that are unique or keys, like email.
Don't forget to clear your DB of the tables so when you run `php artisan migrate` the DB is clear.

Answer (score 0):

A *`migrate:refresh`* command will roll back all of your migrations and then execute the  *`migrate`* command. This command effectively re-creates your entire database:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh

// Refresh the database and run all database seeds...
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

---

Another Solution is: Delete *`users table`* table from the database also delete users entries from *`migrations`* table.

After, execute run the migrate Artisan command: `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

i am sure this will work because i have the same issue but i fixed with this

```
 php artisan migrate:fresh
```

please try and check

**UPDATE**

Delete project and install new laravel project

and do chnages in your .env file and

in database.php

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    ],
```

replace your existiing code to this

and run

```
 php artisan make:auth 

 php artisan migrate
```

or

```
  php artisan migrate:fresh
```

i hope this time it will work

and make sure you have all the requirements install in your system
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when there is already an instance of the table in the migration folder. When you try to install Laravel's auth and chatter forum packages it also creates a user table migration. To solve the problem please go to the migration folder and delete one of the user table migrations. After that, you can run php artisan migrate